# How do I spread out load on my rails app from webhook responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I have a rails app that easily handles the traffic we currently experience, *except* once a day when we receive a large number of pings within a few seconds from an external service's webhook that is reporting on past transactions. Currently this causes the app to time out due to lack of db connection availability, meaning we lose some of the webhooks as well as bringing the site down for a few seconds. It's not important that the data contained in these webhooks be processed instantaneously, so I am looking for a good way to spread out the responses, rather than do an expensive upgrade just to handle these bursts with additional db connection capability.

Is it okay to just have the relevant controller method sleep for a small, random number of seconds before doing anything that would open a db connection to spread things out? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how about a load balancer?  something like nginx?

Comment: Does each request have an unique response or is this something that could be cached? Letting your controller sleep would tie up the web process which is usually very undesirable. You might be able to use model caching with for example Redis or Memcached if the requests use much of the same data.

Comment: @sircapsalot a load balancer would help if the response was cachable - but if you have a number of server that all use the sames database then that is going to be the choke point even if the requests are passed to multiple web processes.

Comment: The formatting across requests is the same but the data contained is different.
We're on Heroku which does some load balancing of its own as I understand it; is there an easy way to deprioritize/delay hits on a certain controller method in a load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a background/async processing system like Sidekiq (or whatever Heroku offers). Modify your controller action to do nothing but shove the parameters into a background job and return "ok".  Then process the job in the background.